# Is there a way to see all the PHP codes processes while/after running a code?

Tags: php, debugging

Well, I'm not that of a PHP hard-coder, but I was just wondering, instead of debugging everything with var_dump/error functions ect', is there maybe a more simple and fun way to debbug my code?

Something that runs on the browser (extention) / server (I use Ubuntu server) / external tool (like Fiddler for example) that can show me exactly what's happening with the code.

Comment: You should take a look at [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: xdebug provides this functionality, which is how your unit tests are able to measure code coverage

Comment: Thank you guys :) 
I read about it and this looks perfect!